# Returning key for object in dictionary gives no visible interface error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have the dictionary like this:

```
{
    Asr = "5:33";
    Dhuhr = "1:11";
    Fajr = "2:40";
    Isha = "11:34";
    Maghrib = "9:28";
    Qiyam = "1:38";
    Sunrise = "4:54";
}
```

I have the value `5:33` stored as a string. I want to return the string `Asr` for this time.

I am using the following code:

```
NSArray *temp = [arrayOfDatesAsDates allKeysForObject:finalTimeFormat];
NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
```

But Xcode says "No visible @interface for NSMutableArray declares the selector 'allKeysForObject'"

Why is this? Is my code to search this name wrong?

Comment: "arrayOfDatesAsDates" is obviously an NSArray, not an NSDictionary.  (As the message is clearly telling you.)

Comment: The dump you show above is of an NSDictionary, but that's not what you're executing `allKeysFOrObject` on.

Comment: (If it really was a dictionary you no doubt would have named it "dictOfDatesAsDates", since, as you certainly know, it's very bad programming practice to misname a variable.)

Comment: It is misnamed I agree, but that is definitely the log output for arrayOfDatesAsDates...

Comment: No, the dump is definitely a dictionary (as evidenced by the `{}` brackets), but the object you're using with `allKeysForObject` is definitely an array (as evidenced by the error message).  Review your logic again -- you're missing something.

Comment: (There are two traps you can fall into:  One is believing that the object type necessarily matches the pointer type -- this is not true in Objective-C -- you can easily get an NSArray into an NSDictionary pointer if you're not careful.  The other trap is to assume that identically named variables contain identical contents -- pointer values are not magically transferred from one declared variable to another with the same name, nor are values magically transferred between two instances of the same class.)

Comment: @samiles: This seems to be your sixth question about more or less the same problem. I don't want to sound rude, I would just suggest that you try to really *understand* the answers that you already got, and perhaps learn a bit more about Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an NSMutableArray, not an NSMutableDictionary. Initialize it with `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` instead of `[NSMutableArray array]`.

Comment: Since it's already been created and used elsewhere in the code, is there a way I can quickly convert it now (or search it as an array)? Thanks

Comment: A dictionary holds objects as keys representing values, and an array stores objects as indexes representing values. You're trying to get the key for an object in an array, but arrays don't have keys.
Edit: Sorry, that came out rather rude. What is the code that initializes the array/dictionary?

Comment: Hmm. So is the whole `Asr = "5:33"` my data in this array? I thought it was a dictionary and `Asr` was the key and `5:33` the object...?

Comment: @samiles - The dump is of a dictionary, but that's not what you're using with `allKeysForObject`.  (An array will be bracketed with `()` in an NSLog dump.)